# iOS: How to tell if an object of type id is a class or a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

This is pretty advanced stuff. I'm messing around with some runtime code as a side project. The problem I'm trying to solve is this: If I have an object of type id, and that object can be a string or a class or a protocol, how do I tell which it is?

For example, here is some code I'm messing with:

```
[objArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        // Do something with the string ...
    } else if (... obj is a Protocol ...) {
        // Do something with the protocol ...
    } else if (... obj is a Class ...) {
        // Do something with the class ...
    } else {
        // It's something we are not interested in!
    }
}];
```

Up until now I've had no problems storing as assortment of NSString, Class and Protocol instances in the array and everything else is fine. The reason I need to detect them is simply that I cannot control what is coming into this code. So I need to establish what the `obj` being processed by the loop is before doing stuff with it.

I've been trying all sorts of runtime functions and stuff but so far no luck if identifying what the object is.

Anyone tried anything like this?

Comment: Protocols are defined as a type of NSObject therefore they can actually be stored in NSArrays and the like. I've already been doing that quite successfully. Obviously what I'm doing is a very dynamic thing and is something that is rarely part of any usually Objective C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because **Protocol** is a subclass of **NSObject** you can detect it the same way you would any other class. What's interesting is that the **Protocol** class has no public interface.

An object of type **id** is either a Class or an instance of a class, so I would test if it is a Class first, and if this fails, it's an instance of a class and therefor use string comparisons to determine the class name. For **Protocol** compare to @"Protocol"

Example-

```
// assign the object to inspect
id obj = //...
NSString *className;
// test for Class type first
if (object_isClass(obj)) {
// it's a Class... inspect further...
className = NSStringFromClass(obj);
if ([className isEqualToString:@"Protocol"]) { /* Protocol Class */ }
}
else {
// must be an instance - get the class name
className = NSStringFromClass([obj class]);

// test for instance of Protocol class
if ([className isEqualToString:@"Protocol"]) { /* Protocol instance */ }

// continue testing for any other classes here...

}
```

NSStringFromClass is found in the [Foundation Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromClass)

Comment: Thanks. Thats pretty much where I was going.

Answer (score 2):

I may have now found the solution.

To test if an id is a Class:

```
NSLog(@"isClass %s", object_isClass(obj) ? "yes":"no");
```

To test if an id is a Protocol:

```
NSLog(@"isProtocol %s", object_getClass(obj) == objc_getClass("Protocol") ? "yes":"NO");
```

These seem to work, although I think there may be a better way to do the protocol check.